# Generate random numbers with known discrete probabilities in Python

Tags: python

I would like to generate random triads of numbers (h, v, d).

The d number is generated according to the random values of h, v following some if statements

h and v are integers within a known interval

Below there is a code example:

```
l="low"
m="medium"
h="high"

for i in range (100):
   h=random.random()*3
   v=random.choice(['low', 'medium', 'high'])

   d1=1
   d1_2=random.randint(1,2)
   d1_3=random.randint(1,3)

   if 0<h<0.5 or h==0:
       if v==l:
           d=d1

       elif v==m:
           d=d1_2

       elif v==h:
           d=d1_3
```

The probability of d1 is 83.3%, the probability of d1_2 is 6.7% whereas of d1_3 is 10%

How can I insert these possibilities in Python???

Thank you very much in advance...

Comment: Is your question about how to calculate a value of `d` given `h` and `v`? In which case, can you write down as text how the numbers are supposed to be generated? Or is it about how to store a list of `(h, v, d)` tuples?

Comment: No my problem is how to generate d values according to their proper probabilities

Comment: You're probably going to be interested in Eli Bendersky's page on [weighted random selection](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/01/22/weighted-random-generation-in-python/).

Answer (score 4):

You want a random element from your list with different weights, right?

```
def weighted_random(weights):
    number = random.random() * sum(weights.values())
    for k,v in weights.iteritems():
        if number < v:
            break
        number -= v
    return k

# the following values can be any non-negative numbers, no need of sum=100
weights = {'d1': 83.3,
           'd1_2': 6.7,
           'd1_3': 10.}

for i in xrange(10):
    print weighted_random(weights),
```

prints, as an example

```
d1 d1 d1 d1_2 d1 d1 d1 d1_3 d1 d1_2
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you would like to have the variable 'v' take the value of d1 with a probability of 0.833 (say p1), d1_2 with probability 0.067 (call it p2) and d1_3 with probability 0.1 (p3)

To do this, you can generate a uniformly distributed number between 0 and 1 and check if the number is less than p1. If it is, then you let it take the first value. If not, you check if it is less than p1 + p2. If so, then you let it take the second value. Finally, if neither of these is the case, then you use the final value. Some simple code would be the following:

```
p_1 = 0.833
p_2 = 0.067
p_3 = 0.1
r = numpy.random.rand()
if r < p_1:
  v = d1
elif r < (p_1 + p_2):
  v = d1_2
else:
  v = d1_3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate chance like so;

**83.3%**

```
import random

rand = random.randint(100,10000) * 0.010

if rand <= 83.3:
    print('success: ' + str(rand))
else:
    print('failed: ' + str(rand))
```

**Example result**

```
192:Desktop allendar$ python test.py
success: 35.7
192:Desktop allendar$ python test.py
success: 60.03
192:Desktop allendar$ python test.py
success: 51.97
192:Desktop allendar$ python test.py
success: 45.58
192:Desktop allendar$ python test.py
failed: 87.53
192:Desktop allendar$ python test.py
success: 33.11
192:Desktop allendar$ python test.py
success: 50.68
192:Desktop allendar$ python test.py
success: 81.8
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Lea](http://code.google.com/p/lea/), a pure Python package dedicated to discrete probability distributions.

```
>>> distrib = Lea.fromValFreqs(('d1',83.3),('d1_2',6.7),('d1_3',10.))
>>> print distrib.asPct()
  d1 :  83.3 %
d1_2 :   6.7 %
d1_3 :  10.0 %
>>> distrib.random(10)
('d1', 'd1', 'd1', 'd1', 'd1_3', 'd1', 'd1', 'd1', 'd1', 'd1_3')
```

Et voilà!